# Does "combat without dice" suffer from an XY problem?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Combat without dice/with minimal dice](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102000/23970) strikes me as, fundamentally, a desirable question.* I know I'd like to see answers to it! But I wonder if it's [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/311001). OP seems to have a simply-identifiable problem: "We like playing 5e in lots of ways, but would like less rolling in combat." And *they've* identified using the DMG's "minimal dice" guidance as their route to take.

Should we be advising this user that they should simply pose their problem, and trust that *if* "use the DMG's 'minimal dice' guidance, here's how I did it" is a good answer, it'll come?

---

<sup>* - It looks like we don't have a good, canonical question on making [5e combat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bdnd-5e%5d%20%5bcombat%5d%20is%3aquestion) less of a grind, believe it or not.</sup>

Comment: It suffers from "combat with dice is a core mechanic" syndrome.  It's like magic without saving throws.  This appears to me to be a question that begs for "are you sure you are using the right game system" in an answer.

Comment: reading the part of the DMG he mentions, the diceless variant rule (p.236) is for non-combat only. Albeit, the DMG is pretty passive-aggressive about saying: "some DMs use dice for combat only"... Is it telling us that combat unavoidably needs dice, that's what I read at least.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast that's exactly the thought I had: I'd love to answer OP with "I've run a 5e out-of-combat/DW in-combat hybrid that seems to solve your problem, blah blah blah" but the way they pose it rules out that sort of answer.

Comment: should we attempt to make that canonical question?

Comment: @Mindwin my instinct would be to let it arise organically. The only time I've posed a "canonical" question that I didn't actually have, I knew I pretty-much had *the* answer in hand ([here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77247/23970)); in this case it's anything-but that cut-and-dry.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes, it does

I suspect that the reason the DMG optional rule is mentioned as the solution is to legitimize the question, so that it wouldn't become an opinion-based Q. While it does the job, it now falls into the XY question category.

It could be improved by citing the DMG optional rule as a precedent, or one of the options they would consider acceptable. If a different solution exists, and since it seems they are open to house rules or homebrew to remove dice from their game, then that solution should not be a frame challenge but instead a valid answer to their Q.

Comment: He's edited it considerably, and seems to be closer to a question that can be reopened.  Point of DMG citation is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

While I believe analyzing the consequences of 'canon' optional rules certainly has its place, it may really not be what this asker is after. Still a legitimate question in its own right though (even the Original version).